# Windows Registry String Value Path

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I'm trying to set up Lock Screen for Users.
I've created a new Registry Key with the three values:

[image: my registry key]

I'm using `%userprofile%` since I don't know all the name of users.
But the Lock Screen is not changing only if I use

> C:\user\pictures\Lock Screen\img.jpg

Is not possible to use `%userprofile%` in a Registry String Value or is there an other way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where in the registry is your key? Why can't you put the image in a folder accessible by all?

Comment: The lock screen is not inside any user (on the lock screen you can select the user to login) so which user do you think it should expend to?

Comment: The lock screen image needs to be accessible by System, since no user is logged in. The default path for this registry key/policy setting is `C:\windows\web\screen\lockscreen.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like a combination of two things.

1. In order for the registry to expand the environment variables like `%userprofile%` or `%public%` you need to use the **REG_EXPAND_SZ** value type (choose ***Expendable String Value*** when creating the value) instead of the standard **REG_SZ** (*String Value*) you have used
2. You're trying to use a user environment variable (%userprofile%) in the context of the lock screen which is before logging in to any user. So which user is it supposed to use? You can only use system environment variables (like `%public%` or `%root%` there.)